# Site Access by Default on Port 80 Producing Unstable Errors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, site-collection, publishing-site, iis

I have a SharePoint 2019 On-Prem site that I have built and configured for authenticated and anonymous access with HTTPS, AAM, and all necessary stuff.

The issue lies for accessing my site externally, it asks for credentials multiple times, throws inconsistent 401 errors, does not allow uploads, etc.

When I tried to refer to some logs, I found that this inconsistent issues are being faced as a result of accessing my site through HTTPS but on port 80 not 443. This behavior is default without doing any such configuration:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken


2023-10-11 11:22:09 10.20.140.181 GET /Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx - 80 - {sourceip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 401 0 0 11
2023-10-11 11:22:09 10.20.140.181 GET /Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx - 80 - {sourceip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 401 0 0 10
2023-10-11 11:22:09 10.20.140.181 GET /Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx - 80 - {sourceip}Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 401 1 2148074254 1
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx - 80 0#.w|{domain}\{user}10.20.140.227 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 59
```

Even it throw errors for assets such as CSS and Images:

```
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/styles/all.min.css - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 401 0 0 3
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/styles/style.css - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 401 0 0 2
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NCMaster/assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css - 80 0#.w|nhic\m.abed 10.20.140.227 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 304 0 0 7
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 401 0 0 2
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/styles/all.min.css - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 401 1 2148074254 1
2023-10-11 11:22:10 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/styles/style.css - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx 401 1 2148074254 1
```

On the other hand, I don't face any issues at all while on port 443 which is by default while using localhost or under my VPN tunnel:

```
2023-10-11 11:20:45 10.20.140.181 GET /SiteAssets/Images/healthrecord.png - 443 - 10.20.254.10 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://oid.nhic.gov.sa/ 200 0 0 313
2023-10-11 11:20:45 10.20.140.181 GET /_catalogs/masterpage/NHICMaster/assets/images/shc_logo.png - 443 - 10.20.254.10 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://oid.nhic.gov.sa/ 200 0 0 503
2023-10-11 11:20:46 10.20.140.181 GET /SiteAssets/Images/mask.png - 443 - 10.20.254.10 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://oid.nhic.gov.sa/ 200 0 0 488
```

Did not capture anything useful from SharePoint ULS logs also.

I am not sure if this issue is produced as a result of using port 80, but at least I am not facing it at all on port 443. Though I did configure the AAM with two Internet URLs (HTTP and HTTPS) with one Public URL for HTTPS and my IIS bindings are configured as well.

Is there a way to ensure that all the traffic goes on port 443 instead of 80 for external public access ? or it is related to something else ?